# Let $A$, $B$ countable, then $A\cup B$ is countable.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$, $B$ countable, then $A\cup B$ is countable.

I cannot use the trivial proof of this, (A is countable then exists a $g_1$ function bijective $A\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, B is countable then exists a $g_2$ function bijective $B\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$

**My work:**

Let $A=\{a_1,\ldots,a_n,\ldots\}$ and $B=\{b_1,\ldots,b_n,\ldots\}$

Let $f:A\cup B\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ such that

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
2i & \text{if } x=a_i \text{with } i\in\mathbb{N}\\
2j-1 & \text{if } x=b_j \text{with } j\in\mathbb{N}
\end{cases}
$$
This function is bijective, then $A\cup B$ is numerable, is correct this?

Comment: What is the difference between a bijection $A\to\Bbb N$ and writeing $A$ as $\{a_,\ldots, a_n,\ldots\}$ except that the latter uses the undefined symbol "$\ldots$"? Also, countable is not the same as countably infinite.- Finally, it may happen that $x=a_i$ and $x=b_j$ at the same time

Comment: What if $x = a_i = b_j$?  And um... what is $n$ did you mean $2i$ and $2j-1$ rather than $2n$ and $2n-1$.

Comment: yeah, sorry @fleablood is that.

Comment: Well, no.  That isn't well defined if $x = a_i = b_j$.  And, how is that not using the "trivial" proof?  You *did* assume that those bijections *did* exist well you listed those values.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I suppose i need make a other case for $A\cap B\not = \empty$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: minor quibble: for many people (not me), *countable* does imply infinite.

Comment: Let C=(a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,....).  $A\cup B \subseteq C$, which is countable.

Comment: The preferred meaning of "countable" is "finite or countably infinite", so that "not countable" means the same as "uncountable".

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: what do you mean by "preferred"?

Comment: @RobArthan. It's what the pros do.